# Is there any way to find which DLLs are being accessed via reflection in .Net application?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, dependencies

I am working on a .Net solution that contains 270 C# projects. They all have a physical reference to each other. But there are some projects which they refrenced each other without any useing/call. For example, project A added project B as a reference but when I remove this reference from the project A  and hit the build button all goes well with no Error. But this still does not tell me that I can safely remove the reference to the project B because there might be some codes that are accessing the project B methods via reflection. Now rescale this example to 270 projects!! Is any tool or solution to find out this kind of dynamic dependencies without going through the line by line of code? I know ReSharper and VS 2017 shows you unused dlls but I am not sure if they consider this corner case as well. (call a dll via reflection)

Comment: I can tell that ReSharper doesn't go trough your code line by line and looks for reflection that might cause the problem. I also don't think visual studio does that. For reflection that works with compile-time constants e.g. `typeof(MyClass).GetProperties()` you need a reference. For reflection that works via strings it is impossible to get all edge cases (what happens when the type name is in a file which gets loaded at runtime or when the type is passed as string into a method?)

Comment: Yes you are totally right and I think that`s why I posted this question overhere. To see if anyone else knows something that I might miss